# Dart's Future Interface (doWhile, microtask and sync)

Tags: flutter, dart

Haven't seen a lot of info about it online...

What are the possible use cases in which I'd want to use, either `Future.doWhile`, `Future.microtask` or `Future.sync`?

#### Future.sync

A lot of times after a button press for example, I'd want a `Future` to happen immediately,
but I wouldn't want it to block the UI, is that a good use case for `Future.sync` or is that better to use `Future` and let dart handle when thing will get executed?

Answer (score 1):

> I'd want a Future to happen immediately...

You can't make Future to happen immediately because it needs some time to be executed. Instead you can block UI thread while future is executing. The pseudo code looks like that:

```dart
T runSync<T>(Future<T> future) {
  while (future.running) sleep(10);
  return future.result;
}
```

This will block your ui thread. That's why we are using Futures. Futures used for specific tasks that's not resolved immediately (usually I/O tasks, eg: network requests, file read/write) to get notified when future resolves without blocking UI thread.

Here's how I'm handling futures without blocking UI thread:

```dart
class MyState extends State<..> {
  bool _running = false;
  
  Future<String> doTask() async {
    // some long running IO tasks
    return 'Hello world';
  }

  Future handlePress() async {
    setState(() { _running = true; });
    try {
      await doTask();
    } finally {
      if (mounted) {
        setState(() { _running = false; });
      }
    }
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Text('Execute'),
      // Disable button if task is currently running to block parallel calls (for example sending same http request twice)
      onPressed: _running ? null : handlePress,
    );
  }
}
```

In this code when user presses `FlatButton` I'm setting `_running` to true to disable `FlatButton` until Future is running.

Comment: Do you ever use `Future.sync`? and where did `mounted` came from?

Comment: İ haven't used `Future.sync` but I'm sure it's not doing what you're intended. `mounted` property coming from `State`. It's `true` if the widget is currently mounted to widget tree. For example it will be false if you navigate away from that screen. It's good practice to check mounted before setting state (usually in async functions) to make sure setState doesnt throws any error